# I tried to get three value from the URL 1)__VIEWSTATE 2)__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR 3)__EVENTVALIDATION, but still cannot get the result from post form

Tags: python, post, beautifulsoup, request

I tried to get three value from the URL 1)__VIEWSTATE 2)__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR 3)__EVENTVALIDATION, but still cannot get the result from post form.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "URL"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

   viewstate = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")['value']
   viewgen = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']
   eventval = soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']

    payload={
        '__VIEWSTATE':viewstate,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':viewgen,
        '__EVENTVALIDATION':eventval,
        'today': '20180624',
        'sortBy':'', 
        'selPartID':'', 
        'alertMsg':'', 
        'ddlShareholdingDay': '23',
        'ddlShareholdingMonth': '06',
        'ddlShareholdingYear': '2018',
        'txtStockCode': '00001',
        'txtStockName':'', 
        'txtParticipantID':'', 
        'txtParticipantName':'', 
        'btnSearch.x': '35',
        'btnSearch.y': '8'
    }

   req = s.post(URL,data=payload,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
   soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it missing the following data, and you dont need to set `__EVENTVALIDATION`

```
'__EVENTTARGET':'btnSearch',
'today': '20181227', # current day not 20180624, put it below
'txtShareholdingDate': '2018/06/24',
```

complete payload

```
payload={
        '__VIEWSTATE':viewstate,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':viewgen,
        '__EVENTTARGET':'btnSearch',
        'today': '20181227',
        'txtShareholdingDate': '2018/06/24',
        'sortBy':'', 
        'selPartID':'', 
        'alertMsg':'', 
        'ddlShareholdingDay': '23',
        'ddlShareholdingMonth': '06',
        'ddlShareholdingYear': '2018',
        'txtStockCode': '00001',
        'txtStockName':'', 
        'txtParticipantID':'', 
        'txtParticipantName':'', 
        'btnSearch.x': '35',
        'btnSearch.y': '8'
    }
```

Comment: dears, i removed __EVENTVALIDATION, and added your code, but it seem not work, thanks !

Comment: yes, dear, and add your code under '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':viewgen, and removed '__EVENTVALIDATION':eventval, 'today': '20180624', 'ddlShareholdingDay': '23',        'ddlShareholdingMonth': '06',   'ddlShareholdingYear': '2018',

Comment: answer edited. I mean is only delete `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` and append above data.

Comment: dear, it seem pop following error : viewstate = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")['value']                                                   ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: dear, i've updated my code, but it seem also not work, please help, thanks !